# Copy the data from one field to another field

Tags: jquery, razor, knockout.js

I am very new to knockout JavaScript and Jquery, I am building a new form in which I have two blocks one for shipping address and one for billing address. I have the check box if incase the billing address is same as shipping, need the address field data to copied to billing from shipping address fields

[image]

```
<div class="form-check">
   <input class="form-check-input position-static" type="checkbox" id="SameAsShippingAddress" value="SameAsShippingAddress" data-bind="checked: sameAsShippingAddress" />
   <label>Check this box if Shipping Address and Billing Address are the same.</label>
 </div>
  
 <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-6">
        <h4>Shipping Address:</h4>
           <div class="form-group required">
             <label for="EmailCompetitor" class="control-label">Email:</label>
             <input type="email" maxlength="150" id="EmailCompetitor" name="EmailCompetitor" class="form-control" data-bind="value: emailCompetitor" required />
            </div>

            <div class="form-group required">
              <label for="FirstNameCompetitor" class="control-label">First Name:</label>
              <input type="text" maxlength="150" id="FirstNameCompetitor" name="FirstNameCompetitor" class="form-control" data-bind="value: firstNameCompetitor" required />
            </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6">
       <h4>Billing Address:</h4>
       <div class="form-group required">
           <label for="EmailCompetitor_Billing" class="control-label">Email:</label>
           <input type="email" maxlength="150" id="EmailCompetitor_Billing" name="EmailCompetitor_Billing" class="form-control" data-bind="value: emailCompetitor_Billing" required />
        </div>

        <div class="form-group required">
           <label for="FirstNameCompetitor_Billing" class="control-label">First Name:</label>
           <input type="text" maxlength="150" id="FirstNameCompetitor_Billing" name="FirstNameCompetitor_Billing" class="form-control" data-bind="value: firstNameCompetitor_Billing" required />
        </div>
    </div>
```

Is there a easy way to map the data from the shipping address field to billing address fields on click of the checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

if($('#SameAsShippingAddress').prop('checked') == true){ $('#EmailCompetitor_Billing').val($('#EmailCompetitor').val()); } else{ $('#EmailCompetitor_Billing').val(''); }

Answer (score 0):

Write a checkbox change function:

```
$('#SameAsShippingAddress').change(function () {
                if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                    $("#EmailCompetitor_Billing").attr("value", $("#EmailCompetitor").val());
                } else {
                    //do sth
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you would normally handle this is with the change function and checking if the checkbox has been checked:

```
// Listen for when the object with ID SameAsShippingAddress  (input type:checkbox) changes
$("#SameAsShippingAddress").on("change", function (e) {
    // Is the checkbox checked?
    if(this.checked) {
        // If checked, put the shipping address information into the billing address information
        $("#EmailCompetitor_Billing").val($("#EmailCompetitor").val());
        $("#FirstNameCompetitor_Billing").val($("#FirstNameCompetitor").val());
    }
});
```

**Note:** you can clear the data by adding an else statement so the whole code will look like this:

```
// Listen for when the object with ID SameAsShippingAddress (input type:checkbox) changes
$("#SameAsShippingAddress").on("change", function (e) {
    // Is the checkbox checked?
    if(this.checked) {
        // If checked, put the shipping address information into the billing address information
        $("#EmailCompetitor_Billing").val($("#EmailCompetitor").val());
        $("#FirstNameCompetitor_Billing").val($("#FirstNameCompetitor").val());
    } else {
      // (if not checked / unchecked) Remove billing information
      $("#EmailCompetitor_Billing").val(""));
      $("#FirstNameCompetitor_Billing").val("");
    }
});
```

...but this will likely result in bad user experience as the user may have already filled information or slightly edited the shipping address information after checking the box.